# Trying to uninstall Fglrx-driver but xvba-va-driver has dependencies

Tags: drivers, uninstall, fglrx

I have been trying to uninstall fglrx- driver for quite a while now, but the more I try, the more I fail ;)
I actually don’t know how I installed it, but now I want to uninstall first, because I have to install some 32-bit libs, which are locked up by fglrx. When trying to uninstall, I get stuff like:

```
flex@NEWORLD-LI:~$ sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
[sudo] password for flex: 
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Hinweis: »fglrx-amdcccle-updates« wird für regulären Ausdruck »fglrx*« gewählt.
Hinweis: »xorg-driver-fglrx-dev« wird für regulären Ausdruck »fglrx*« gewählt.
Hinweis: »fglrx« wird für regulären Ausdruck »fglrx*« gewählt.
Hinweis: »fglrx-driver-dev« wird für regulären Ausdruck »fglrx*« gewählt.
Hinweis: »fglrx-updates« wird für regulären Ausdruck »fglrx*« gewählt.
Hinweis: »glx-alternative-fglrx« wird für regulären Ausdruck »fglrx*« gewählt.
Hinweis: »fglrx-control-qt2« wird für regulären Ausdruck »fglrx*« gewählt.
Hinweis: »fglrx-updates-dev« wird für regulären Ausdruck »fglrx*« gewählt.
Hinweis: »fglrx-dev« wird für regulären Ausdruck »fglrx*« gewählt.
Hinweis: »fglrx-glx« wird für regulären Ausdruck »fglrx*« gewählt.
Hinweis: »xfree86-driver-fglrx-dev« wird für regulären Ausdruck »fglrx*« gewählt.
Hinweis: »fglrx-amdcccle« wird für regulären Ausdruck »fglrx*« gewählt.
Hinweis: »fglrx-driver« wird für regulären Ausdruck »fglrx*« gewählt.
Hinweis: »fglrx-control« wird für regulären Ausdruck »fglrx*« gewählt.
Paket »fglrx-glx« ist nicht installiert, wird also auch nicht entfernt.
Paket »fglrx-control-qt2« ist nicht installiert, wird also auch nicht entfernt.
Paket »xfree86-driver-fglrx-dev« ist nicht installiert, wird also auch nicht entfernt.
Paket »xorg-driver-fglrx-dev« ist nicht installiert, wird also auch nicht entfernt.
Paket »fglrx« ist nicht installiert, wird also auch nicht entfernt.
Paket »fglrx-amdcccle-updates« ist nicht installiert, wird also auch nicht entfernt.
Paket »fglrx-dev« ist nicht installiert, wird also auch nicht entfernt.
Paket »fglrx-updates« ist nicht installiert, wird also auch nicht entfernt.
Paket »fglrx-updates-dev« ist nicht installiert, wird also auch nicht entfernt.
Paket »glx-alternative-fglrx« ist nicht installiert, wird also auch nicht entfernt.
Probieren Sie »apt-get -f install«, um dies zu korrigieren:
Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 xvba-va-driver : Hängt ab von: fglrx-driver (>= 1:10-9) oder
                                 fglrx (>= 2:8.840) soll aber nicht installiert werden oder
                                 fglrx-updates (>= 2:8.840) soll aber nicht installiert werden
E: Unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten. Versuchen Sie »apt-get -f install« ohne Angabe eines Pakets (oder geben Sie eine Lösung an).


flex@NEWORLD-LI:~$ sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove fglrx*
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Hinweis: »fglrx-amdcccle-updates« wird für regulären Ausdruck »fglrx*« gewählt.
Hinweis: »xorg-driver-fglrx-dev« wird für regulären Ausdruck »fglrx*« gewählt.                                                                                                      
Hinweis: »fglrx« wird für regulären Ausdruck »fglrx*« gewählt.                                                                                                                      
Hinweis: »fglrx-driver-dev« wird für regulären Ausdruck »fglrx*« gewählt.                                                                                                           
Hinweis: »fglrx-updates« wird für regulären Ausdruck »fglrx*« gewählt.                                                                                                              
Hinweis: »glx-alternative-fglrx« wird für regulären Ausdruck »fglrx*« gewählt.                                                                                                      
Hinweis: »fglrx-control-qt2« wird für regulären Ausdruck »fglrx*« gewählt.                                                                                                          
Hinweis: »fglrx-updates-dev« wird für regulären Ausdruck »fglrx*« gewählt.                                                                                                          
Hinweis: »fglrx-dev« wird für regulären Ausdruck »fglrx*« gewählt.                                                                                                                  
Hinweis: »fglrx-glx« wird für regulären Ausdruck »fglrx*« gewählt.                                                                                                                  
Hinweis: »xfree86-driver-fglrx-dev« wird für regulären Ausdruck »fglrx*« gewählt.                                                                                                   
Hinweis: »fglrx-amdcccle« wird für regulären Ausdruck »fglrx*« gewählt.                                                                                                             
Hinweis: »fglrx-driver« wird für regulären Ausdruck »fglrx*« gewählt.                                                                                                               
Hinweis: »fglrx-control« wird für regulären Ausdruck »fglrx*« gewählt.                                                                                                              
Paket »fglrx-glx« ist nicht installiert, wird also auch nicht entfernt.                                                                                                             
Paket »fglrx-control-qt2« ist nicht installiert, wird also auch nicht entfernt.                                                                                                     
Paket »xfree86-driver-fglrx-dev« ist nicht installiert, wird also auch nicht entfernt.                                                                                              
Paket »xorg-driver-fglrx-dev« ist nicht installiert, wird also auch nicht entfernt.                                                                                                 
Paket »fglrx« ist nicht installiert, wird also auch nicht entfernt.                                                                                                                 
Paket »fglrx-amdcccle-updates« ist nicht installiert, wird also auch nicht entfernt.                                                                                                
Paket »fglrx-dev« ist nicht installiert, wird also auch nicht entfernt.                                                                                                             
Paket »fglrx-updates« ist nicht installiert, wird also auch nicht entfernt.                                                                                                         
Paket »fglrx-updates-dev« ist nicht installiert, wird also auch nicht entfernt.                                                                                                     
Paket »glx-alternative-fglrx« ist nicht installiert, wird also auch nicht entfernt.                                                                                                 
Probieren Sie »apt-get -f install«, um dies zu korrigieren:
Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 xvba-va-driver : Hängt ab von: fglrx-driver (>= 1:10-9) oder
                                 fglrx (>= 2:8.840) soll aber nicht installiert werden oder
                                 fglrx-updates (>= 2:8.840) soll aber nicht installiert werden
E: Unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten. Versuchen Sie »apt-get -f install« ohne Angabe eines Pakets (oder geben Sie eine Lösung an).


flex@NEWORLD-LI:~$ sudo apt-get install fglrx-opdates fglrx fglrx-driver
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Paket fglrx-driver ist ein virtuelles Paket, das bereitgestellt wird von:
  fglrx-updates 2:9.012-0ubuntu1
  fglrx 2:9.010-0ubuntu3
Sie sollten eines explizit zum Installieren auswählen.

E: Paket fglrx-opdates kann nicht gefunden werden.
E: Für Paket »fglrx-driver« existiert kein Installationskandidat.
```

I hope someone is able to read the german stuff, if not i can translate ;)
thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can access to all the Ubuntu repositories, especially the one rated as "*restricted*" or "*multiverse*". Go to `Software sources` for this and check the corresponding check boxes (in the Ubuntu Software tab) :

[image]

If you get some some updates, install them : `sudo apt-get upgrade` in a terminal or with the graphic `Update Manager`. `apt-get install` may give errors if packages are no updated to their latest version.

Comment: thanks for the help, i tried to force uninstall, and when my graphiks-shell broke, i disided to re-install, install all x32-lib's and fglrx + updates and since then it works fine :) thank you though